# Merging 2 sorted linked list not getting desired output

Tags: data-structures, merge, linked-list

Below code is not working...
I'm trying to merge 2 linked-lists using iterative function..
but it is not giving desired output..it is printing elements infinitely
i'm learning programming..
help me out...
thanks in advance...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct Node
 {
   int data;
   struct Node *next;
 }list_node;



list_node* MergeLists(list_node *headA, list_node* headB)
{
  if (headA == NULL && headB == NULL) {
     return NULL;
  }

   if (headA == NULL) {
    return headB;
}

if (headB == NULL) {
    return headA;
}

if (headA->data > headB->data) {
    list_node *tmp = headB;
    headB = headA;
    headA = tmp;
}

list_node *listHead = headA;

while (headB) {

    while (headA->next != NULL &&
           headB->data > headA->next->data) {
        headA = headA->next;
    }


    list_node* nextB = headB->next;
    headB->next = headA->next;
    headA->next = headB;
    headB = nextB;
   }

    return listHead;
}

 list_node* push(list_node* head_r, int new_data)
  {
    list_node* new_Node = (list_node*)malloc(sizeof(list_node));

    new_Node->data  = new_data;
    new_Node->next = head_r;
    head_r = new_Node;
    return head_r;
  }

void Print(list_node* head_r)
{
   while(head_r)
    {
      printf("%d\n", head_r->data);
      head_r = head_r->next;
    }


 }

 int main()
 {

   list_node* l_list = NULL;
   list_node* l_list2 = NULL;
   l_list = push(push(push(push( push(l_list, 1),2),3),4),5);
   l_list2 = push(push(push(push( push(l_list, 6),8),3),4),0);
   MergeLists(l_list, l_list2);
   printf("Merge 2 Sorted list \n");
   Print(l_list);
   return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Note: most of your code (about 80%) is intended to handle *special cases*. By using a pointer-to-pointer to node you can avoid *all* spcial cases, reducing the merge function to about five lines of code

Comment: please use a for loop for the l_list assignment!

Comment: please mark if the answer was correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on this line `l_list2 = push(push(push(push( push(l_list, 6),8),3),4),0);`
I assume it's supposed to be `l_list2 = push(push(push(push( push(l_list2, 6),8),3),4),0);`

What happened is that you now have 2 variables pointing to the same list. When you then do the merge you try to merge the list into itself. Because with every step of the merge algorithm your list gets bigger, it never finishes.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
if (headA->data > headB->data) {
        list_node *tmp = headB;
        headB = headA;
        headA = tmp;
    }
```

should be

```
if (headA->data > headB->data) {
        list_node *tmp = headB;
        headB = headA;
        headA = *tmp; //tmp is a pointer
    }
```

And in

```
l_list2 = push(push(push(push( push(l_list, 6),8),3),4),0);
```

should be

```
l_list2 = push(push(push(push( push(l_list2, 6),8),3),4),0); //l_list2
```